# What library needs to be installed for -lz compile flag

Tags: software-installation

I have the following error after typing the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The error message is as follows:

```
...
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/etree.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1


----------------------------------------
Command "/home/<user_id>/.../<virtualenv_name>/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-SBDLKx/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-OSju9J-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/<user_id>/.../<virtualenv_name>/include/site/python2.7/lxml" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SBDLKx/lxml/
```

What missing library needs to be installed (for `-lz`) on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a library linked with `-lfoo`, look for `libfoo.so` and packages that provide it. [`libz.so` is provided by](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libz.so&searchon=contents) `zlib1g-dev`.